# массовая смена стилей

Tags: css

доброго времени суток, можно ли в css каким либо образом указать блоку стилей(любое количество) конкретного родителя, например просто `.class{}` начнет искаться от `html`, интересует реально ли сделать так что бы он искался не от `html`, а от указанного селектора? это могло бы решить проблемы при интеграциях и пересечением стилей, + уменьшение длинны селекторов

Answer (score 0):

То что вы хотите реализовано в [sass](https://sass-scss.ru/) и [less](http://lesscss.org/#). Например, в sass можно писать так:

```
body{
  property: value;

  .selector1{
    property: value;
    property: value;
    property: value;

    .selector2{
      property: value;

      &__item1{
       property: value;
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

этот же код в css выглядел бы так:

```
body {
  property: value;
}
body .selector1 {
  property: value;
  property: value;
  property: value;
}
body .selector1 .selector2 {
  property: value;
}
body .selector1 .selector2__item1 {
  property: value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, легко, укажите родителя и через пробел его стили будут применяться длях всех потомков. Демонстрация:

```css
/* применить стили к p для всех потомков .rough-parent */
.rough-parent p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Это просто параграф</p>

<div class="rough-parent">
  <p>Это параграф особо крутого родителя</p>
</div>
```